# New excel formulas have issue when creating a formula for whole row

Tags: excel

I am new to doing excel formulas. I added my formula to the first row of a certain column of spreadsheet. I want to add it for the rest of the rows in the table. I try dragging down the bottom of the formula row and it does copy the formula all the way to the bottom of the table like I want. However, it now just displays the formulas and not the actual calculated value.
How do I get it to see the calculated value?

If I select the formula wizard for one of the formulas it shows the calculated value towards the bottom but the value in the table is just the formula and not the calculated value.

Comment: Did you remember to use `=`?

Comment: Did your first formula display properly?  I just want to make sure you had the = prefix.

Comment: the first formula just displayed the forumula and not the actual calcluated valueu.

Comment: Your cells are likely formatted as 'Text'. Switch to 'General'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have automatic calculation turned off.  For Excel versions 2007 and beyond, go to the Formulas Ribbon and select "Automatic" from the Calculations Options Item.  For earlier versions, go to: Tools, Options, then click the Calculations tab.  On this tab. select the "Automatic" radio button.  If you are in manual calculation mode, pressing F9 will calculate the formulas.

Answer (score 1):

... If it shows up in your formula wizard, the only thing I can imagine it being is that you are in `Show Formula` mode.

check out [This link](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformulas/qt/show_formulas.htm)

### EDIT:

The only other issue I can think of is that there was an issue in earlier versions of Excel 2007 where XLSX from XML files had this issue - Try applying the latest Excel Service packs.

Comment: The hotkey for that is Ctrl + ` (That is the same key the ~ is on)

Comment: I tried this and it still is displaying the formula. I tried with other docs and it worked. I created this worksheet from XML document. Is there any thing that could mess things up that way????????????????????????????? Thankx

Comment: The only other issue I can think of is that there was an issue in earlier versions of Excel 2007 where XLSX from XML files had this issue - Try applying the latest Excel Service packs. (Adding this to my answer for completeness' sake)